# Track an Android phone through its IMEI

Tags: mobile, android

My mobile phone got stolen few days back. I tried all possibilities to track it, the only option is through IMEI. Can I know which SIM card is running on that specific IMEI?

Comment: I think you want to locate the IMEI of the phone not of the SIM, aren't you ?

Comment: i want to locate the Sim card active on my IMEI. so i can commence ahead tracin the location..is it possible ?

Comment: Have you notified the police and your phone company? The phone company can put a block on the IMEI so that the phone cannot be used (anywhere on any SIM), unless the thief knows how to change the IMEI.

Answer (score 7):

It is very possible to identify the SIM based on the IMEI if the phone is powered on, and on the network. The problem is that you most likely do not have access to this information unless you work for the carrier, and typically these guys don't care about your stolen phone enough to disclose this information. Sorry for your loss and good luck.

Comment: is it possible through carrier services ? do they really have access to which sim card is active on a specific IMEI. ?

Comment: @akshaynathani Yes.