# I want to track my android phone using IMEI

Tags: android, imei

My phone was stolen last week. I went to the police to track it but still now no result.

What software can I use to track my device just using the IMEI of the phone?

Comment: This is not a security question.  And no such software exists, what you would need is access to the cell network towers, those could track it if the device is active.

Comment: contact your mobile phone provider who might be able to track it for you

Comment: Possible dupe: [Track an Android phone through its IMEI](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/37119/59741)